# Understanding dir %%a 1>nul 2>nul in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Got this batch file which does exactly what I want, however I don't fully understand what its coding is doing can somebody run me through it?

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('mountvol ^| find ":\"') do (
dir %%a 1>nul 2>nul
if not ErrorLevel 1 (
del /s /f %%ahuntthisfile.txt
del /s /f %%aandthisfiletoo.txt
)
)
```

particularly the `dir %%a 1>nul 2>nul` has got me stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `dir %%a 1>nul 2>nul` lists the content of the folder, and it redirects the command output to the null device.

Comment: Yes, 1 is stdout, 2 is stderr. It's telling both outputs to direct to null, so the dir command won't display anything.

Comment: It seems like that line and the following one are the equivilent of `If Exists "%%a" (`.